# C# - How can i set default value for combobox datagridview from datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have added combobox in datagridview using datasource. Here is the code.

```
private void ExtractExcel(string filename)
    {
        allColumnName = allColumnName.Remove(allColumnName.Length - 1);
        string sqlMatchedData = "SELECT SOURCE_NAME, DESTINATION_NAME, DATA_TYPE, convert(integer, 100 * SIMILARITY) AS SIMILARITY " +
                                        "FROM TB_LOOKUP_COLUMN WHERE SOURCE_NAME IN (" + allColumnName + ") ORDER BY SIMILARITY ASC";
        ds = databaseManager.GetData(sqlMatchedData);

        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "SOURCE_NAME";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "DESTINATION_NAME";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "SIMILARITY(%)";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "DATA_TYPE";

        foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
           int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
           dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = row[0].ToString();
           dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = row[3].ToString();

           columnDestination = row[1].ToString();
           columnType = row[2].ToString();
           comboboxDestinationColumn(columnDestination, n);
           comboboxDataType(columnType, n);
        }

        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
    }


    private void comboboxDestinationColumn(string columnDestination, int n)
    {
        string sqlLookupColumn = "SELECT LookUpColumnID, SOURCE_NAME FROM TB_LOOKUP_COLUMN ORDER BY SOURCE_NAME ASC";
        DataSet dsColumn = databaseManager.GetData(sqlLookupColumn);

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboboxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        comboboxColumn.Items.Add("Please Select");

        foreach (DataRow row in dsColumn.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            comboboxColumn.Items.Add(row[1].ToString());
        }
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1] = comboboxColumn;
    }
```

I am not sure how can i set default value for the combobox, provided `columnDestination` is the default value.

I have tried using `DefaultValuesNeeded` and `CellFormatting` but i think it is not suitable for my condition.

Any suggestion or code example are highly appreciated ?

Comment: After the last foreach : `comboBoxColumn.Value = comboBox.Items[0]`

Comment: @ZwoRmi THANK YOU SO MUCH!